Can I have 2 colons in one sentence?
I want to provide certain highlights for one of our activities. Please advise if a colon or a semicolon would be better for the latter part of the sentence. The 2 sentences are given below:

ABC Segment: 1000 leads received (65% of H1FY24): xx orders (7%) converted worth Rs. yy Cr
XYZ Segment: 1000 leads received (65% of H1FY24); xx orders (7%) converted worth Rs. yy Cr

Thanks!

These aren't really sentences: they're items in a list and could equally well be presented as fields in a table. So you can do what you like, whether it's full stops, commas, colons, or whatever, but try and keep it consistent.

You cannot mix 2 and one like that. It's gross. Spell out your numbers. :)

@tchrist Paraphrasing Orwell's Sixth: Avoid anything gross.

I’m voting to close this question because it uses punctuation in ways that are distanced from grammatical function; these are not sentences, but lists of phrases, and there is no way to say what is "correct."

A semi-colon would be correct for the latter part. The first strand is introducing the list (some also use a dash instead of a colon, though this is often proscribed).
The second part is clearly a list and should be delineated with appropriate punctuation, which can be a semi-colon or comma.
As noted by Stuart F, this is not the most intuitive way to present the data. Using a table, or separating the descriptor and list with a new line, would make it clearer.
